# Which chapter of the One Punch Man webcomic should I start on after seeing the anime?

Tags: one-punch-man

I just finished episode 12 of the anime and I'm under the impression that this is the end of season 1. I'd like to continue with the manga now. I don't want to read the remake; I want to read the original webcomic that started in 2009.

Which chapter should I start on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should start from **Chapter 42** of the original manga.

After the destruction caused by Boros and his defeat by Saitama, the space ship is taken by Metal Knight. The Hero Association HQ is rebuilt.

Chapter 42 picks off with S Class hero, King (ranked 7) *facing off* a reptile monster and then, Dushimof, a machine god created by the Organisation.

Comment: do you know which volumes one has to get after the anime?

Comment: An anonymous user tried to edit this post to indicate that the correct chapter is actually #50. (I don't know whether this is correct or not.)

Comment: @utdev: Um, both OnePunch Man manga series don't have volumes. They're just published chapter-wise.

Comment: @senshin: There are two One Punch Man manga series. That edit was pointing out to the manga chapter of the One punch man series drawn by Murata Yuusuke. The OP is asking for the original version, done by ONE.